# how loop through return ajax data using jquery?

Tags: jquery

My test.php file contains the following information that is sends list of information.

```
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($testResults))
       {
           echo "<li>" . $row['test'] . "</li>";
       }
```

Output:

```
       <li> test A </li>
       <li> test B </li>
       <li> test C </li>
       <li> test D </li>
       <li> test E </li>
       <li> test F </li>
       <li> test G </li>
       <li> test H </li>
```

I need the ajax code to loop through each list coming the php echo command

```
        $.post("test.php", function(data)
        {
            $.each(data, function(key, value)
            {
                  alert(value);
            });
        });
```

The above code is display elements tag symbols and name and text node but I only want it to display only the textnode (test A).

Comment: Then remove the `<li>` part from your PHP code?

Comment: Why don't you just return the data you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` isn't an array or a jQuery object, so `$.each` can't loop through it as-is.

Just convert the `data` into a jQuery object first:

```
$.each($(data), function(key, value) {
      alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to trim the string and remove the `<li>`s by passing the `value` string into the jQuery function -

```
alert($.trim($(value)​.text()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your php script return JSON (not required but simplifies your task), with a simple `json_encode($results);`

Then in your js `$.each(data, function () { // this means array item here });`

Answer (score 0):

check if php gives a JSON object , if so this will work

```
$.each(data,function(key, value){
 alert(value);
});
```